# Chartjs - How to add margin/padding between stacked bars

Tags: chart.js

In Chartjs, it is possible to stack bars. Is it possible to add a margin or padding between the elements? See the red arrow in the screenshot for the desired area to create space between the rendered values.

Example taken from docs [here](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/bar/border-radius.html)

Config:

```
const config = {
  type: 'bar',
  data: data,
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        position: 'top',
      },
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'Chart.js Bar Chart'
      }
    },
    scales: {
      x: {
        stacked: true,
      },
      y: {
        stacked: true
      }
    }
  },
};
```

Setup:

```
const DATA_COUNT = 7;
const NUMBER_CFG = {count: DATA_COUNT, min: -100, max: 100};

const labels = Utils.months({count: 7});
const data = {
  labels: labels,
  datasets: [
    {
      label: 'One Value',
      data: Utils.numbers(NUMBER_CFG),
      borderColor: Utils.CHART_COLORS.red,
      backgroundColor: Utils.transparentize(Utils.CHART_COLORS.red, 0.5),
      borderWidth: 2,
      borderRadius: 16,
      borderSkipped: false,
    },
    {
      label: 'Another Value',
      data: Utils.numbers(NUMBER_CFG),
      borderColor: Utils.CHART_COLORS.blue,
      backgroundColor: Utils.transparentize(Utils.CHART_COLORS.blue, 0.5),
      borderWidth: 2,
      borderRadius: 16,
      borderSkipped: false,
    },
        {
      label: 'Yet Another Value',
      data: Utils.numbers(NUMBER_CFG),
      borderColor: Utils.CHART_COLORS.blue,
      backgroundColor: Utils.transparentize(Utils.CHART_COLORS.blue, 0.5),
      borderWidth: 2,
      borderRadius: 16,
      borderSkipped: false,
    }
  ]
};
```

[image: Stakced Bar Example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this is not possible, but what you can do is add another dataset that sits in between the 2 datasets from which you make the background and bordercolor of the bar transparant

Comment: That's awesome  Thank you for your response. I may have to do that!